# Bluetooth communications with C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I want to write 2 programs with C# one work on PC, the other work on a windows mobile phone.

So I want the PC program to send a signal via Bluetooth ( 1 byte maybe) to the windows mobile phone. and the mobile program (which work on background) handles and accepts this byte without the need of pairing.

how to code this?

please I need any kind of help.

Answer (score 4):

My library [32feet.NET](http://32feet.codeplex.com/) should be useful...

Device Discovery can be done with BluetoothClient.DiscoverDevices, and sending data should be done with classes BluetoothClient and BluetoothListener, see the [User Guide](http://www.alanjmcf.me.uk/comms/bluetooth/32feet.NET%20--%20User%20Guide.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If your phone can use Serial Bluetooth adapters (RFCOMM), you could send it using the serial class.